# How to prevent pixel mixing when doing scroll and mouseWheel operation with fixed elements in a panel in c#winform

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, mousewheel

i am trying to do scroll and mousewheel, and dragging in a panel with textboxes in it. I have to let some of the textboxes with fixed position, but doing this, i have some problem with pixels, while Wheeling or dragging or scrolling. I do not know if there is some sort of way of doing this without this problem. If anyone know an answer and he/she are willing to help, please, feel free.
I will put the code i use for this:

This code is Inside a function that is called from Dynamics NAV and will create the operations:

```
#region PROPRIETES DU PANEL

        pnOperation.Name = idOperationL.ToString();
        pnOperation.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        pnOperation.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        pnOperation.Size = new Size(220, 40);
        pnOperation.Top = posOperationL * 40;
        pnOperation.AllowDrop = true;

        if (nRolesG > 6)
        {
            //I fixed the operation here so they will stay at position 0
            pnOperation.Top = posOperationL * 40;
            pnOperation.Left = 0;

            MainPanel.MouseWheel += (senderL, eL) =>
            {
                pnOperation.Left = 0;
                pnOperation.Invalidate();
            };
            MainPanel.Scroll += (senderL, eL) =>
            {
                pnOperation.Left = 0;
                pnOperation.Invalidate();
            };
        }                        

        #endregion
```

Screenshot[image: Normal one]

Screenshot[image: The mixed one]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post screenshot, please.

Comment: Already post Sr.Sinatr

Comment: Is it owner-drawn `Panel`? Try to call panel `Invalidate()` as you scroll (perhaps by using [`Scroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scroll.aspx) event). Otherwise, show how you do that *fixed elements* part, you may do it wrong (could be possible fixed again with panel `Invalidate()`).

Comment: i updated the post to show you how i fix. I make a condition where i fix the operations to the left side of my mainPanel. So whenever there is a scroll or a mouseWheel operations it should remain at that position if the scroll is horizontal. If is vertical then i should be able to scroll. For the roles is the opposite.I don't know i explain myself good. The invalidate() didn't work, so maybe i am doing it wrong, what do you think?Thanks again

Comment: Show that *fix the operations to the left side of my mainPanel* in code please. What you are trying to achieve is called *frozen* columns (I think). It's a standard feature in `DataGridView` (see [Frozen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.frozen.aspx)) from the box. Create and put a lot of controls on `Panel` is not optimal and disregards how you do it there will be performance issues and graphical glitches (which are mostly fixed by re-painting - calling panel `Invalidate()`). Have you considered to use owner-drawn `DataGridView`?

Comment: I edited the code and put a message so you can see where is doing the fix. The possibility for datagridview is not in my hands, i will ask my boss about it. I am quite new doing this job and i struggle sometimes but i am learning a lot. Thanks. What does it mean from the box??

Comment: [From the box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_feature). It is still unclear how you doing freezing. Is it event, which event, what is `nRolesG`, etc.? Your best bet to get answer is to prepare minimum project where problem is reproducible for others. It is often happens, what while making this (reproducing error in new project and preparing it to show to others) you will find error by yourself.

Comment: I am going to make a little project for the problem can be seen better. Thanks